# How to identify the column used to partition a table from the Postgres system catalogs

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, postgresql-10

Given a table created as so...

```
CREATE TABLE measurement (
    city_id         int not null,
    logdate         date not null,
    peaktemp        int,
    unitsales       int
) PARTITION BY RANGE (logdate);
```

How do I identify which column it's been partitioned on? - in this case 'logdate' solely by querying the postgres catalog.

I've looked in the obvious places in the catalog (pg_class, pg_index) but nothing springs out.

(Using version 10.5)

Comment: @McNets - "select * from pg_class where relkind='p'" gives me those tables that are partitioned, it doesn't tell which column they've been partitioned on (not that I can see anyhow!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not a PostgreSQL pro, but digging a bit I've founded a solution that perhaps can help you. (Works only for version 10 or above)

First I've slightly modified you table by adding two columns to the partition definition (just to show you the final result):

```
CREATE TABLE measurement (
    city_id         int not null,
    logdate         date not null,
    peaktemp        int,
    unitsales       int
) PARTITION BY RANGE (city_id,logdate);
```

This is my solution:

> ```
> select 
>     par.relnamespace::regnamespace::text as schema, 
>     par.relname as table_name, 
>     partnatts as num_columns,
>     column_index,
>     col.column_name
> from   
>     (select
>          partrelid,
>          partnatts,
>          case partstrat 
>               when 'l' then 'list' 
>               when 'r' then 'range' end as partition_strategy,
>          unnest(partattrs) column_index
>      from
>          pg_partitioned_table) pt 
> join   
>     pg_class par 
> on     
>     par.oid = pt.partrelid
> join
>     information_schema.columns col
> on  
>     col.table_schema = par.relnamespace::regnamespace::text
>     and col.table_name = par.relname
>     and ordinal_position = pt.column_index;
> ```
>
> ```
> schema                      | table_name  | num_columns | column_index | column_name
> :-------------------------- | :---------- | ----------: | -----------: | :----------
> fiddle_ctcqwfrzpcyngmgnqkdy | measurement |           2 |            1 | city_id    
> fiddle_ctcqwfrzpcyngmgnqkdy | measurement |           2 |            2 | logdate
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=80bbfc5f472b1fa0d2f8c6953548615b)*

#### [pg_partitioned_table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-partitioned-table.html)

> The catalog pg_partitioned_table stores information about how tables
>   are partitioned.

Unnesting `partattrs` you can get column index of each row involved in the partition. Then you can join `information_schema.columns` just to retrieve the name of every column.

```
+-----------+------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------|
| partattrs | int2vector | pg_attribute.attnum | This is an array of partnatts values that indicate          |
|           |            |                     | which table columns are part of the partition key.          |
|           |            |                     | For example, a value of 1 3 would mean that the first       |
|           |            |                     | and the third table columns make up the partition key.      |
|           |            |                     | A zero in this array indicates that the corresponding       |
|           |            |                     | partition key column is an expression, rather than a simple |
|           |            |                     | column reference.                                           |
+-----------+------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Comment: quote "I'm not a PostgreSQL pro" consider yourself promoted!

Comment: I'm glad to help.

Answer (score 4):

The answer by McNets already helps, but here is a query that produces slightly prettier output:

```
select c.relnamespace::regnamespace::text as schema,
       c.relname as table_name, 
       pg_get_partkeydef(c.oid) as partition_key
from   pg_class c
where  c.relkind = 'p';
```

Below is output that the above query produces:

```
 schema │ table_name  │      partition_key       
────────┼─────────────┼──────────────────────────
 public │ measurement │ RANGE (city_id, logdate)
(1 row)
```